# Lipschitz condition: if $f$ is differentiable at $b$, then $f$ is Lipschitz of order $1$ at $b$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

I have been trying to solve this, but failing at it. 
Since $f$ is differentiable at $x$, we have

$f'(x)=\lim_{y \to x}  \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}= L$

To prove the proposition, all I need to show is

$|f(y)-f(x)|\le C|y-x|$; but since I cannot apply the MVT at a point, I am lost how to get rid of the $\lim_{y \to x}$ from the defintion of the derivative at $x$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Will you please precisely define "Lipschitz at $b$"?  (And perhaps use consistent notation; $b=x$?)  Do you mean if $f'(b)$ exists, then there exists $C>0$ and $\delta>0$ such that $|y-b|<\delta$ implies $|f(y)-f(b)|\leq C|y-b|$?

Comment: Try using a linear approximation to $f(x)$ instead: $f(x)=f(b)+L(x-b)+R$ where $R$ is some "nice" remainder term.

Comment: @JonasMeyer: yes, sorry didn't realize I switched the terms. And yes to the second question as well. But can you just say that?
Officilly $f$ is Lipschitz of order $\beta$ at $x$ if there is a constant $C$ such that $|f(y)-f(x)|\le C|y-x|$ for all $y$ in an interval around $x$.

Comment: @icurays1: can I do the following: 
since Lipschitz is for all $y$ in an interval around $x$, can I then write $f'(x)(y-x)=f(y)-f(x)$, ie, I can find a nbd $P$ of $x$ such that the previous rearrangement of the derivative held? After that, I can take the absolute values and proceed.

Comment: @user43901: "But can you just say that?" No, you are supposed to prove it; I just wanted to make sure I knew what the statement to be proved is.  Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**  From the definition of limit, one can show that if $\lim_{y\to b} g(y)= L$, then there is a $\delta\gt 0$ such that $|g(y)|\lt |L|+1$ if $|y-b|\lt \delta$.

Comment: And from continuity we get if $|y-b| < \delta$, then $|f(y)-f(b)|< <\epsilon$. Or is that not even necessary since we can just say that.

Comment: I am not sure you understood the hint. So a little more, use $g(y)=\frac{f(y)-f(b)}{y-b}$. The point is that if we have differentiability at $b$, then the "differential quotient" cannot be very big near $b$. That will give you the desired Lipschitz condition directly.

Comment: Ah, let me see if I am getting this right then. Another try: since the difference quotient converges, then we can write $|g(y)| < |f'(b)|+1$, which is the Lipschitz. Did I goof up again? :)

Comment: More or less OK, but this only needs to hold "close enough" to $b$, not necessarily for all $y$. And probably you should explain the "magic" $|f'(b)|+1$, which I deliberately left for you to do.